# Rails : add namespace to resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I currently have this in my `routes.rb` :

```
namespace :api
  namespace :v1
   namespace :me
    # ...
    resources :offers do
     resources :state, only: %i(index)
    end
  end
 end
end
```

This gives me this route :

```
GET v1/me/offers/:offer_id/state(.:format)
api/v1/me/state#index
```

But the route I would like to have is this one :

```
GET v1/me/offers/:offer_id/state(.:format)
api/v1/me/offers/state#index
```

Simply put, I want to be able to place my `state_controller.rb` in an `offers` folder, without changing the path to access it.
How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a better way to do it : use `module`

```
resources :offers, module: :offers do
  resources :state, only: %i(index)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define controller for your resources explicitly:

```
resources :state, controller: 'offers/state'
```

This will route requests to `app/controllers/api/v1/me/offers/state_controller.rb`.

Comment: Is there no way to achieve this without specifying the controller ? Looks a bit "ugly" to me :(

Comment: I'm not sure but it might work as well: `controller: 'offers/state'`. I cannot think about anything else.

Comment: Indeed, it works with `controller: 'offers/state'`. However, it doesn't with `controller: 'api/v1/me/offers/state'` (the path is not right). You should edit your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace :api
  namespace :v1
   namespace :me
    # ...
    resources :offers do
      namespace :offers, path: "" do
        resources :state, only: %i(index)
      end
    end
  end
 end
end
```